# ¿Por qué se ven los querys en el navegador?

Tags: php, sql

Tuve un problema con **MySQL** y tuve que desinstalar el **XAMPP** y volverlo a instalar.

Luego de esto, cuando voy a la página que hice (probando unas consultas ahi...) las **queries** de dichas consultas se ven en el navegador, no se esta ejecutando ninguna consulta, pues.. Así como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando **PDO** y mi base de datos esta en **Navicat**.

```
<?php
$db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oficina','root','');
?>
<h3>Consultas multitabla (group by, inner join, left y right)</h3>
empleado <img src="Captura.gif">
oficinas <img src="Captura2.gif">
<h3>Cantidad de oficinas agrupadas por ciudad</h3>
<? 
$query=$db->query("select ciudad,count(*) as v from oficinas group by ciudad");
$query=$db->execute($query);
?>
<table>
    <?
    while($rw=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $cantidad=$rw['v'];
        $oficinas=$rw['ciudad'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Hay <?echo $cantidad?> oficinas en <?echo $oficinas?></td>
    </tr>
<?}?>
```

Comment: ya intentas ejecutar la pagina desde localhos?

Comment: tu base de datos no esta en navicat, ese es tu cliente, si usas xampp tu base de datos es mysql o maria

Comment: bueno, exacto. eso quise decir jaja.. tengo las tablas en navicat.. Se que esta en mysql

Comment: Puedes verificas tus etiquetas de **php**. Porque según veo en la imagen es que están mal colocadas. Lo otro que seria bueno, es que colocaras tu script completo para ver como colocaste las etiquetas **php** (<?php ?>).

Comment: Este codigo me funcionaba perfecto hasta que desinstale el xampp. Cuando lo volvi a instalar ya no me funciona el codigo. Las etiquetas php estan bien puestas en el codigo. de todas maneras tomare foto de mi codigo para que vean

Comment: Si me dices que el código te funciono bien, entonces el problema esta en el servidor **xampp**. Has la siguiente prueba para ver si el servidor esta funcionando bien el **php**. Crea un script dentro de la carpeta htdocs y ponle dentro el siguiente código <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> si esta funcionado correcto te muestra la configuración.

Comment: @Yohanna, lo que dice **Yoel** parece ser el problema. ¿Estas segura de que tienes habilitada la opción [_short_open_tag_](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)?

Comment: Yo opino que está haciendo echo a las consultas. Puedes poner el código?

Comment: EL CODIGOOOO D:

Comment: <?php

 $db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oficina','root','');
?>
<h3>Consultas multitabla (group by, inner join, left y right)</h3> 
empleado
<img src="Captura.gif">

oficinas
<img src="Captura2.gif">

<h3>Cantidad de oficinas agrupadas por ciudad</h3>
<?
 $query=$db->query("select ciudad,count(*) as v from oficinas group by ciudad");
 $query=$db->execute($query);
?>
<table>
<?while($rw=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 $cantidad=$rw['v'];
 $oficinas=$rw['ciudad'];
?>

 <tr><td>Hay <?echo $cantidad?> oficinas en <?echo $oficinas?></td></tr>

<?}?>

Comment: Disculpen que lo haya puesto asi de feo xD No supe poner la imagen.. jaja

Comment: no se entiende mucho

Comment: Antes tenías xampp configurado para que maneje los short_open_tags para correr código php entre las etiquetas `<? ... ?>` en vez de `<?php ... ?>`. Ahora cuando desinstalaste e instalaste de nuevo, tienes las configuraciones por defecto, por lo que ahora no entiende las etiquetas <? ... ?>. Corrige todas tus etiquetas `<?` a `<?php` o haz lo que te dijo @MarcosGallardo

Answer (score 2):

El error parece deberse a que tienes deshabilitado la opción [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

> Indica a PHP si debería permitirse la forma abreviada de las etiquetas de apertura de PHP (`<? ?>`). Si se quiere utilizar PHP junto con XML, se puede desactivar esta opción para poder usar `<?xml ?>` en línea. Si no, puede imprimirse con PHP, por ejemplo: `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>`. Además, si está desactivada, se debe usar siempre la forma no abreviada de la etiqueta de apertura de PHP (`<?php ?>`).

### Soluciones:

**Opción 1:**

Modificar todas las aperturas de código `PHP` cortas (`<?`) por `<?php`.

**Opción 2**

Activar `short_open_tag`, siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

- Abrir el archivo `php.ini` (`ej: c:/xampp/php/php.ini`).
- Buscar el texto `short_open_tag` y modificar su valor a `short_open_tag = On`.
- Cerrar y guardar el archivo `php.ini`.
- Reiniciar el servidor `Apache`.

Answer (score 1):

Es un desorden tu código

```
<?php 
  $db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oficina','root',''); 
  $query=$db->query("select ciudad,count(*) as v from oficinas group by ciudad"); $query=$db->execute($query);
  $output='';
  $output.='
  <h3>Consultas multitabla (group by, inner join, left y right)</h3>    
  empleado <img src="Captura.gif"> oficinas <img src="Captura2.gif"> 
  <h3>Cantidad de oficinas agrupadas por ciudad</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>';
  while($rw=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  { 
    $output.='<td>Hay '.$rw['v'];.'oficinas en '.$rw['ciudad'].'<td>';
  } 
  $output.='<tr>
  </table>';

  echo $output;
?>
```

El problema con lo que pusiste es que te faltaban etiquetas PHP.

Saludos.

Comment: Disculpame, pero esa no es una buena forma de hacer las cosas, veo más desorden aquí.